# Problem: Javascript iframe send the postMessage() before iframe completed loading

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have iframe in parent.html. Child.html sending the postMessage('documnent.cookie','*') to the parent window.

The problem is postMessage() send 'null'. postMessage() is triggered before iframe loading is completely done.  I have to postMessage() to Parent window only if iframe completely loads the data.

Here is my code: parent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<body id="Body" style="background-color:Silver">

  <iframe id ="CA_FRAME_0" src="http://localhost/ibmcognos/bi/child.html" style="display:none"></iframe>

  <script type="text/javascript">  

    window.addEventListener("message", function (e){   


    if(e.data == null){         
        alert('fail');                

    }else{      
        alert('sucess');           
        document.cookie="key=" +e.data + ";expires=0;path=/";           
    }       

    }, false);  


</script>

<div id="arcContainer" class="arcContainer"></div>  

    <script type="text/javascript">     

        ARCPLAN.language = "XXX";
        ARCPLAN.application = "lv02";
        ARCPLAN.startDocName = "application.apa";
        ARCPLAN.arcCgiSite = "http://localhost/.....";      

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

//child.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <title>COOKIE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> </head> <body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getCookie(name) {      var arg = name + "=";       var alen = arg.length;      var clen = document.cookie.length;      var i = 0;      while(i < clen) {           var j = i
+ alen;             if(document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
                return getCookieVal(j);             i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;            if(i == 0)
                break;      }       return null;    }

    function getCookieVal(offset) {         var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);      if(endstr == -1)            endstr = document.cookie.length;        return document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr);   }   
            **parent.postMessage(getCookie("key"), "*");**   </script>

**<iframe id ="CA_FRAME" src="http://localhost/ibmcognos/bi/" style="display: none;" ></iframe>**   - *this url make the redirect from here and set the cookie, it takes time* 

</body> </html>
```

Kindly provide me some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In this case we have a webpage A need to load another webpage B through `iframe`.
page A is loaded. we can add a custom event to listen page B load event.

page A code:

```
const iframeWin = document.getElementById('h5-iframe').contentWindow;
window.addEventListener(
  'message',
  (e) => {
    const { data } = e;
    console.log('receive page load', data);
    if (data.pageLoaded) {
      iframeWin.postMessage(youdata, '*');
    }
  },
  false,
);
```

page B code:

```
window.addEventListener(
  'message',
  (e) => {
    console.log('receive youdata', data);
    const { data } = e;
  },
  false,
);

// after register listen function send this message to page A.
window.parent.postMessage({ pageLoaded: true }, '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onload event to your iFrame:

```
<iframe id ="CA_FRAME" src="http://localhost/ibmcognos/bi/" onload="onCaFrameLoad(this)" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Then you can run JS code only after the frame has completely loaded:

```
function onCaFrameLoad() {
    // wrap your post in this function
};
```

This way, the code will only run once the frame has finished loading.

PoC:
parent.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        PARENT- I get data from child
        <br /><br />
        <iframe id ="CA_FRAME_0" src="child.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

child.html

```
<html> 
    <body>
        CHILD - I send data to parent - but only after CA_FRAME has loaded
        <br /><br />
        <iframe id ="CA_FRAME" src="inner.html" onload="onCaFrameLoad(this)"></iframe>
        <script>
            function onCaFrameLoad() {
                alert('iframe has loaded! now you can send data to the parent');
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

inner.html

```
<html> 
    <body>
        INNER - I load all my content, then the onCaFrameLoad function in child.html runs
        <script>
        alert('My Name is INNER - I load all my content first');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this earlier and now also but facing the same problem. I have one iframe in parent and one in child also. its from different origin.

Comment: Which iframe sends to the other? Parent to child or child to parent?

Comment: child.html send cookie data using postMessage('key', '*')  to parent.html. 'key' is one cookie data from the child iframe url.

Comment: Have you tried adding the onload event to the parent iframe and the listener js to the child's script?

Comment: I havent understood.. How can I make it. I need data only from child to parent not vice-versa..kindly clarify me or show some sample snippet if possible.

Comment: Ok, but you need to make it clearer which iFrame you need to have loaded. What I understood right now: Parent - gets data from child | Child - send data to parent once CA_FRAME has loaded      -> is that correct?

Comment: yes, your understanding is right:) child iframe 'url' make the redirect and takes some time to load and set the cookie, before that postMessage() check the cookie and send null. postMessage() should wait until all the data get loaded in cookie from ifram in other words all redirection should happen.   * If this tough to achieve, can i use pop up?? But again data has to be loaded and get the cookie to set in parent window.

Comment: Here is a working example with the function from my answer. I'll also add the code from the parent, the child and the inner iframe to the answer. http://alexa-freudenstadt-marktplatz.de/test/parent.html If this does not work for you, maybe your problem isn't the order of the loading, but some problem with the data you want to send?

Comment: Thanks for your time and code. As you said it could be the order in which its getting called may be.. I will check it in my end.

Comment: It worked well with the help of your sample. Thanks a lot @Sirence